# Excel Cell Value from 2 Cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, cells

I have a query that feeds into Excel, with 2 different date columns. Either both columns will be blank or one of them will have a date value in it.

I want to determine if one cell has a value and put that value into a 3rd cell or leave it blank.

[image]

I keep attempting to put together AND, IF and ISBLANK statements and nothing has worked.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What if both contains a date?

Comment: That should not happen. but if it does, it needs to choose the latter of the 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
=IF(A2="",IF(B2="","",B2),A2)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! I knew it was something ridiculously simple and I just couldn't wrap my brain around it!

Answer (score 0):

In **C2** enter

```
=IF(AND(A2="",B2=""),"",IF(A2="",B2,A2))
```

If **both** cols have a value, then the col **A** value is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Returns the higher of the two. If both blanks, then return a blank.

```
=IF(MAX(A2:B2)<>0,MAX(A2:B2),"")
```